# In Oracle, how would I begin to create the tables when all the needed tables have both foreign and primary key constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

In Oracle, 
Lets say there are 3 tables with primary key and foreign key on each table. So, If i were to start creating the tables, how would i start. I started to create a first table with primary and foreign key but It don't let me create a table when there is foreign key mentioned without creating other referenced table. 
if this the case, I can't create any of this tables, Because i foreign key on all 3 tables and primary on each table. 
Note: Yeah, I know i could add the constraint later. but i'm curious to know, how does thing kind of issue work in real world programming. do developers add the foreign constraint later or ummmm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the foreign key constraint to be `DEFERRABLE`, which allows you to have Oracle check the constraint at the end of a transaction.

```
SET TRANSACTION;
    SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
    INSERT INTO TABLE_ONE (PK1, FK2, NAME)
        VALUES(10, 20, 'Foo');
    INSERT INTO TABLE_TWO (PK2, FK3, NAME)
        VALUES(20, 30, 'Bar');
    INSERT INTO TABLE_THREE (PK3, FK1, NAME)
        VALUES(30, 10, 'Baz');
COMMIT;
```

After each of the first two `INSERT`s, there is a foreign key with no referent, but Oracle won't check until the commit. After the third insert, everything is fixed.

Do you want this data structure though?

Answer (score 1):

> "Lets say there are 3 tables with primary key and foreign key on each
>   table. "

In the real world that couldn't happen.  There must be at least one table which has no foreign key dependency on any other table.

In fact it's likely to be more complex than that.  Most data models ave two sorts of tables: lookup (or code) tables and business data tables.  There must be at least one business data table which doesn't depend on any other business data table, one which sits at the top of the tree.

> "do developers add the foreign constraint later"

It depends.  Generally speaking it is useful to have separate scripts for different sorts of DDL, so yes, it is common to create the tables in one pass, build indexes in another and add  constraints afterwards.  Such a strategy would be appropriate if the database phase includes data loading.

But if the delivered database will be empty - except for lookup data - the tables can be built in a singe script.  In which case we need to order the script so that we build the tables without foreign key dependencies first, then build their children, then the grandchildren, and so on.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not so sure about an absolute statement like "there must be at least one table which has no FK dependency" - there's nothing in the relational model of data which precludes it, for one thing; and while I can't think of a good obvious example right this instant I'm sure there are some - i.e. where you have a circular chain of references.

Comment: A simple example might be employees, managers and departments. Each employee must be in one department (DEPT 1:m EMP). Each department must have one manager (MGR 1:m DEPT). Each manager is an employee (EMP 1:1 MGR). (of course, this is only one of several possible models for the world of employees, managers and departments, many of which may be ones with a "top of the tree" entity) I'm not sure if this proves my point yet, I'm not quite happy with this example so I reserve the right to change my opinion :)

Comment: I agree that this is a really unlikely situation. A database should be a representation of a particular data environment, and the constraints and normalisation should guarantee that the natural rules of that environment cannot be violated in the database. For this situation to arise you'd need a "real" situation where multiple entities could not exist without others already existing, and if I found myself modelling something like this my first reaction would be that I'd made an error.